# Selenium 4.x trying to POST CDP: "UnsupportedCommandException"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I`m trying to execute some commands via CDP, however no matter what combination of Selenium/Driver/Chrome I use it's always the same result.

Last tested with:

- Selenium 4.1.1
- Chrome + Driver 96.0.4664.110

The project is made in C so I am posting manually to Selenium via CURL. Every other command besides CDP works fine.

I have checked Selenium, Chrome Driver; they both have the CDP support built in.

The URL's I tried to post to are:

```
- /session/id/goog/cdp/execute
- /session/id/{}/cdp/execute
```

The posted data format is: "cmd" + "params" (json object).

Both end in the same result: *org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException*.

I also tried to run Selenium in different modes, standalone, hub/node, same result.

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong? Or maybe I have misunderstood the usage?

Comment: Do you use chromedriver? Can you chare the curl example for creating a new session?

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka Just do a simple POST to huburl/session with desiredCapabilities + requiredCapabilities as a JSON object.

Comment: @Mecanic I've did a try to run CDP command for chromedriver and `POST /session/id/goog/cdp/execute` works for me. See details in my answer.

Comment: After some investigate I discovered, that there is difference when you work with the local chromedriver and with selenium-grid. I suspect when you create session with selenium grid, you will get `se:options` object with `cdp` url. And cdp endpoint should be used for cdp commands.

Comment: For selenium-grid I see `ws://` cdp url returned, I think it means that selenium-grid doesn't support cdp command end-points and delegates cdp requests to be performed by clients directly. It you have to sent and recieve ws messages using some ws command line tool instead of curl. So, I think using chromedriver executable is easier way.

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka Thanks, after testing your answer it does indeed seem to work. However this does not explain why Selenium does not accept the command, when it's there (I checked source code), and frankly I need to post to Selenium.

Comment: I believe remotewebdriver has CDP... local does not.

Comment: @pcalkins Hm... what do you mean exactly? Needs external IP?

Comment: There's a "HasCdp" boolean, that (if I remember right) is set to false for local, and true for remote.

Comment: @pcalkins Indeed I saw something similar in the source code. I just don't get what "remote" means when you run the same thing as "local"...

Comment: I think Selenium Grid provides the stuff you need for CDP... so it's outside of the driver? Not real sure why local doesn't have it.  (might need a websockets server??)

Comment: @pcalkins Darn... I tried to run Hub/Node and it still returns ""se:cdp": "ws://192.168.1.111:4444/"...

Comment: I agree, selenium server jar contains `\org\openqa\selenium\devtools\` with a lot of classes, so it could work.

Comment: This really, really sucks. I`m investigating the code in Selenium better, maybe there is a way just not documented.

Comment: @Mecanik I've tried to find the way how to execute cdp on selenium-grid chrome node, but no luck.. I still think selenium-grid just not proxies this commands.. it was designed this way, or just a bug. I can suggest you, if you like to work with remote browser to launch several chromedriver-executable processes with defined ports and allowed-ips list and this way you'll be able to execute cdp commands. Otherwise I can suggest to create an issue to selenium project on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using chromedriver executable

**This worked for me (Windows + Postman), but should also work with CURL Linux/Mac.**

*1 Download chromedriver: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads for your chrome version.*

*2 Start chromedriver*

```
start chromedriver.exe
```

output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 97.0.4692.71 on port 9515...
```

*3 Send requests to localhost:9515/*

- 3.1 Create Session:

```
POST localhost:9515/session

request json body:
{"capabilities":{"goog:chromeOptions": {}}}

status 200

response:
 "value": {
        "capabilities": {
            ...
        },
        "sessionId": "b8ac49ce2203739fa0d32dfe8d1a23b5"
```

- 3.2 Navigate some url (optional, just check request by sessionId works):

```
POST localhost:9515/session/b8ac49ce2203739fa0d32dfe8d1a23b5/url

request json body:
{"url": "https://example.com"}

status 200
```

- 3.3 Execute CDP command (take screenshot):

```
POST localhost:9515/session/b8ac49ce2203739fa0d32dfe8d1a23b5/goog/cdp/execute

request json body:
{"cmd":"Page.captureScreenshot", "params":{}}

status 200

response:
{
    "value": {
        "data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA...."
    }
}
```

#### Allow remote connections

By default chromedriver allows only local connections.

To allow some remote IPs:

```
start chromedriver.exe --allowed-ips="some-remote-ip"
```

Reference: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/security-considerations

### Run CDP commands with Selenium Grid

Eventually, it started to work for me with

- ChromeDriver 97.0.4692.71
- selenium-server-4.1.1
- Chrome 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Note: Content-Type header should have charset=utf-8
`Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8` for Selenium Grid HTTP requests.

##### Prerequisites

*1 Download and run selenium server according to*
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/getting_started/

```
java -jar selenium-server-<version>.jar standalone --driver-configuration display-name='Chrome' stereotype='{"browserName":"chrome"}'
```

*2 Create Session:*

```
POST localhost:4444/wd/hub/session

request json body:
{
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "goog:chromeOptions": {
      "args": [
      ],
      "extensions": [
      ]
    }
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "goog:chromeOptions": {
          "args": [
          ],
          "extensions": [
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

status 200

response:
{
    "status": 0,
    "sessionId": "69ac1c82306f72c7aaf53cfbb28a30e7",
    ...
    }
}
```

*3 Execute CDP command (take screenshot):*

```
POST localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/69ac1c82306f72c7aaf53cfbb28a30e7/goog/cdp/execute

request json body:
{"cmd":"Page.captureScreenshot", "params":{}}

status 200

response:
{
    "value": {
        "data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA...."
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation, I decided to go the web socket route. I've implemented myself the necessary code to send commands via web socket, however it gets stuck infinitely. On the other hand testing via command like, I always get "JSON: invalid token at position 0"; even if it's a valid JSON. I really don't understand how people use Selenium in this state...

Comment: I have one last idea of how to make it work, I'll try and come with feedback.

Comment: @Mecanik hey, eventually it started to work for me with selenium-grid too. I'll update Selenium Grid section.

Comment: Many thanks, I am very curious how.

Comment: @Mecanik the trick was in the new session request body... I watched the selenium-client new session request payload and reproduced it. And it works.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see anything new that I haven't tried, maybe you forgot to post full details/data? ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240952/discussion-between-max-daroshchanka-and-mecanik).

Comment: Sure, see you there.